# How to run python script from termux?

Tags: python, termux

I have managed to run the script from my computer with a cronjob. Was hard to accomplish but I've managed to see some sense. The problem is that most of the time I am not on my computer and wanted the script to run periodically. I know there are services like AWS or Google Cloud but was curious if it would be possible to run from my cellphone. That's why I ended up trying termux.

The problem is I can't figure out how to make it work and why it doesn't work.

My cronjobs on my mac are :

```
*/5 * * * * /PATH.TO/python3 /PATH.TO/main.py
30 * * * * /PATH.TO/python /PATH.TO/TEST.Json.py
```

Even tho I take the same logic and apply it to my phone, it doesn't work

```
*/1 * * * * /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/scripts/script.py
```

Why's that?

Comment: I don't believe that cron is supported on termux/android

Comment: It did generate a log file when I asked it to, but couldn't get to see what's in it. File's there, but seems empty...

Comment: consider doing what is suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14308309/1734130) to debug your issue

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking into Termux:Tasker here: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Tasker

You should be able to attach a cronjob process to Tasker and specify it to run in the background.

Unfortunately, it is 1.99$. You'll need Tasker and Termux:Tasker.
Start by opening Termux. and type `mkdir -p .termux/tasker`. Move to the newly created folder with `cd ./termux/tasker` and use `vim` or `nano` to create your script. You'll probably have to do `pkg install python` too.

Then move to Tasker, create a task and name it whatever you want. Inside the task, add a Plugin:Termux command and set the config to the script you're running. I'd put at least 15 seconds before the timeout just in case. If you coose to run it in terminal you'll see the output, or you can add another command, this time Alert:Flash with the text `%stdout`. This will show the output of the previous command, in this case the python script.

Last step is to create a profile to trigger the task. I'm not sure what exactly you want it to trigger on, but for example you can have it go off every 2 minutes, every time you connect to a Wi-Fi network, or every time you receive a text. Then simply point it to the task you created earlier.

Comment: Termux and Termux Tasker should be acquired from F-Droid.  Not because I said so, but because Google Play is for anything Termux is End Of Life https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/pkujfa/important_deprecation_notice_for_google_play/

That is also a good thing because the price tag is now $0.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have been in the same situation you are stuck at. Did you perform the following actions?:

1. Acquire wakelock on your phone
2. `crond start`

If yes, then does your program run without cron, like if you do:
`/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/scripts/script.py`

Comment: Any time I see that /data/data/* path I ask myself if that is a glitch.